# After rd.break RHEL 9 goes to maintenance mode

Tags: grub2, password

Yesterday I had a certification exam to RHEL9 and I had to recover the root password.

I did this procedure hundred times succesfully with the same version but yesterday, after I put `rd.break` at the end of the line starts with "linux" and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, the systems went to maintenance mode and asked for the root password instead of opening a shell to mount `/sysroot`.

If I don't edit `grub` file on boot, the server starts correctly. I tried to recover the password in the other server but encountered the same problem.

Does anyone know what happened, or what it is I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should use: `rd.break enforcing=0`